# Python, pythonic expression

Tags: python

Is there pythonic expression for this snippet?

```
# linux.cmd is a dict
cmd = linux.cmd.get(k, k)
if not cmd:
    cmd = k
```

The value of `linux.cmd.get[k]` could be `False`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is the first line, sice the second paramter to dict.get() is the default value anyway. That construct returns k if k is not in dict. IF dict can return a value that evaluates to false add a " or k" to the end of the first line.

Comment: the value of `linux.cmd.get[k]` could be false

Comment: Oh, then you can add " or k" to he end of the first line. Better would be ensure there was no false value possible.

Comment: ok thanks, that works, can you mod your answer likewise too?  I need false values so that k is value as well.